# Hidden Message: Code and Calculation

Tags: cipher

There is a hidden message that can be decipher from the string below. Try to figure out what does it actually says. The final answer will be in text form.

> TkyeasliuewthhnvsttegpwrueeoawdhshheanwhwloeestoatdiesorfhTtlkhocaordeehhdTtekrnTtnleathhsetlhhdpmtheatd

Hint: When X becomes the unlucky one, Y = 2X - 18.

You don't actually need anything else other than the string of characters and the hint above. The 4 capital 'T' are intentional (not text error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The heart knows only valor.  The sword that defends the helpless.  The might that uphold the weak.  The wrath that undoes the wicked

I'm not entirely sure what the hint means, but I assumed that "the unlucky one" means

> the number 13.

It turns out that this is

> a simple transposition cipher.  If you arrange the text in rows of 13 characters, and then read down the columns, you get the solution text:
>
> ```
> Tkyeasliuewth
> hnvsttegpwrue
> eoawdhshheanw
> hwloeestoatdi
> esorfhTtlkhoc
> aordeehhdTtek
> rnTtnleathhse
> tlhhdpmtheatd
> ```

Comment: Congrats. The hint is actually about vertical and horizontal count, I just don't want to make it to obvious.